# Testing AutoCompleteTextView in Android

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

I'm using Robolectric to test my Android app, and I've come across this problem: In my MainActivity, I have this code:

```
private DelayAutoCompleteTextView textview_departure;
<snip>
textview_departure.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

            JsonPlace place = (JsonPlace) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
            departureName = place.getPlaceName();
            textview_departure.setText(departureName);
            uniqueDepartureStation = place.getID();

        }
    });
```

The DelayAutoCompleteTextView is copied from [here](http://makovkastar.github.io/blog/2014/04/12/android-autocompletetextview-with-suggestions-from-a-web-service/). 
Anyway, the problem I have is that in order to test my MainActivity, I need the code above to be executed from my test class. Unfortunately, there isn't any ShadowAutoCompleteTextView class implemented in Robolectric, so I'm not sure how to perform a click on an item in the list provided by the AutoCompleteTextView.

Any suggestions on how to get this test up and running?

Answer (score 1):

It depends exactly what actions you need to do. The shadows are there to help with the tests. They sometimes help initialise view or get/set data from them that would otherwise be unable to access. This doesn't mean that you can't do anything without a shadow.

If you are able to construct your DelayAutoCompleteTextView without problems in the tests and can use the normal methods to access the data from it that you need, you could get away without using a Shadow at all. Just find it using findViewById() and work with it as normal. To perform clicks on any View, you can call the method callOnClick.

If you can't do what you need, you can always make your own custom Shadow for this view, as explained here: http://robolectric.org/custom-shadows/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I looked into triggering the onItemClick without using a shadow object, and think this might be a start:          AutoCompleteTextView textview_departure = (DelayAutoCompleteTextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.text_departure); 
  textview_departure.getOnItemClickListener().onItemClick(null, textview_departure, 0, 0);

The "null" must be replaced by a working parent reference, but I haven't found a way to set this parameter properly. Any suggestions?

Comment: What I'm suggesting would be textview_departure.callOnClick(). That's a method in the View class itself.

Comment: That would work if the textview_departure had an OnClickListener, but won't AFAIK work on an OnItemClickListener.